# Full Outer Join en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, join

mi consulta es como realizar un FULL OUTER JOIN en Laravel, tengo la version 5.1

Ejemplo:

[image: a busy cat]

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Deberías dar más información al respecto, pues no sé entiende el objetivo de la pregunta en el caso de que hubiese (que no hay). Un saludo David777

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días he encontrado esto, tal vez te sirva:

```
->join('Entradas',function ($join) {
$join->on('Entradas.paci_CodigoNumerico', '=', 'Turnos.paci_CodigoNumerico')
->on('Entradas.medi_Codigo', '=', 'Turnos.medi_Codigo')
->on('Entradas.espe_Codigo', '=', 'Turnos.espe_Codigo')
->on($this->raw('convert(varchar, Entradas.entr_Fecha, 112)'), '=', $this->raw('convert(varchar, Turnos.turn_FechaTurno, 112)'))
->on('Entradas.ubic_Codigo', '=', 'HorarioMedico.ubic_Codigo'), null, null, 'full outer';
```

Te paso el link para que puedas verlo mejor.
https://laravel.io/forum/06-19-2014-outer-join-clousure